# perl regex quantifier matches makes unexpected match

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on learning perl and attempting exercises in book. I also don't have strong experience with regular expressions.

I'm attempting to find IP addresses in a file. I wrote a random log.txt file with some IP "addresses" I'm not exactly attempting to validate quite yet but I'm trying to match four sets of 1 to 3 digits separated by a '.'

My code takes a file name and runs line by line in that file and pulls out a match for an IP address.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "poop\n";

foreach my $arg(@ARGV) {
        print "$arg\n";
}

print "The file name is: $ARGV[0]\n";
$file = $ARGV[0];
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( $line =  <$info> )  {
print $line;
  if( $line =~ /(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})/ ){

    my $digit = $1;
    print "A match is: $digit \n";
  }
}

close $info;
```

Here is my log file:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
apple
cat
banana
chariot
zebra
yellow
123.543.98.32
2.2.3.4
1.3.4.55
1.2.3.454
1.1.1.1
22.22.22.22
333.333.333.333
012.345.678.910
012.345.678.91
012.345.678.9
this shouldn't work!!::::
1234.41.123.0
```

And here are my run results:

```
$ perl stringsTest.pl ./log.txt
poop
./log.txt
The file name is: ./log.txt
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
A match is: 1 2 3 4 
apple
cat
banana
chariot
zebra
yellow
123.543.98.32
A match is: 123.543.98.32 
2.2.3.4
A match is: 2.2.3.4 
1.3.4.55
A match is: 1.3.4.55 
1.2.3.454
A match is: 1.2.3.454 
1.1.1.1
A match is: 1.1.1.1 
22.22.22.22
A match is: 22.22.22.22 
333.333.333.333
A match is: 333.333.333.333 
012.345.678.910
A match is: 012.345.678.910 
012.345.678.91
A match is: 012.345.678.91 
012.345.678.9
A match is: 012.345.678.9 
this shouldn't work!!::::
1234.41.123.0
A match is: 1234.41.123
```

This last match is the one I'm confused by.

I thought the quantifiers that I use should limit the match to 1 to 3 digits. I suspect greediness is a suspect. Can someone explain to me why this matches while leaving off the ".0" ?

```
1234.41.123.0
A match is: 1234.41.123
```

Answer (score 2):

An unescaped period in a regular expression means "any character except newline."  You'll need to escape it to match an actual, literal period in the input.

```
  if( $line =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/ ){...}
```

And that's the `poop`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be to match the regex to starting with '^' and ending with '$'.  The "^" operator denotes the start of an expression while "$" denotes the end.

Example: (\d{1,3}). \ would match strings "123." and "11123." as 1 to 3 digits are true for both cases.

I have used the below program to list the valid ip addresses. From my list of four. Try removing ^ and $ and you could see weird results of 4 digit IPs as well.

```
my $ip1 = "127.0.0.1";
my $ip2 = "1.02.003.1234";
my $ip3 = "127.0.0.10";
my $ip4 = "1267.0.0.1";    
my @ips = ($ip1, $ip2, $ip3, $ip4);

for (@ips) {
    if ($_ =~ /^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/){
        print "$_\n";
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around your regex:

```
if( $line =~ /\b(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\b/ ){
#      here __^^                      and here __^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is being weird, then the thing you want is (aside from 'your problem is probably not a good one for a regex anyway'):

```
use re 'debug';
```

This gives you (for your last example, otherwise it's a bit too verbose):

```
Compiling REx "(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   CURLY {1,3} (6)
   5:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
   6:   REG_ANY (7)
   7:   CURLY {1,3} (10)
   9:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  10:   REG_ANY (11)
  11:   CURLY {1,3} (14)
  13:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  14:   REG_ANY (15)
  15:   CURLY {1,3} (18)
  17:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  18: CLOSE1 (20)
  20: END (0)
stclass POSIXU[\d] minlen 7 
Matching REx "(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})" against "1234.41.123.0"
Matching stclass POSIXU[\d] against "1234.41" (7 bytes)
   0 <> <1234.41.12>         |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <1234.41.12>         |  3:CURLY {1,3}(6)
                                  POSIXU[\d] can match 3 times out of 3...
   3 <123> <4.41.123.0>      |  6:  REG_ANY(7)
   4 <1234> <.41.123.0>      |  7:  CURLY {1,3}(10)
                                    POSIXU[\d] can match 0 times out of 3...
                                    failed...
   2 <12> <34.41.123.>       |  6:  REG_ANY(7)
   3 <123> <4.41.123.0>      |  7:  CURLY {1,3}(10)
                                    POSIXU[\d] can match 1 times out of 3...
   4 <1234> <.41.123.0>      | 10:    REG_ANY(11)
   5 <1234.> <41.123.0>      | 11:    CURLY {1,3}(14)
                                      POSIXU[\d] can match 2 times out of 3...
   7 <234.41> <.123.0>       | 14:      REG_ANY(15)
   8 <234.41.> <123.0>       | 15:      CURLY {1,3}(18)
                                        POSIXU[\d] can match 3 times out of 3...
  11 <234.41.123> <.0>       | 18:        CLOSE1(20)
  11 <234.41.123> <.0>       | 20:        END(0)
Match successful!
poop
1234.41.123.0A match is: 1234.41.123 
Freeing REx: "(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})"
```

As you can see - the gotcha is that line 6 - "REG_ANY".

The situation is worse than you think though, because your regex is actually matching:

```
1234.41.123
```

And ignoring the trailing `.0` anyway. But you're also not anchoring your pattern - so if you do escape the `.`:

```
/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/
```

That compiles up as:

```
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   CURLY {1,3} (6)
   5:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
   6:   EXACT <.> (8)
   8:   CURLY {1,3} (11)
  10:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  11:   EXACT <.> (13)
  13:   CURLY {1,3} (16)
  15:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  16:   EXACT <.> (18)
  18:   CURLY {1,3} (21)
  20:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
  21: CLOSE1 (23)
  23: END (0)
```

Bit closer, but because we don't have any anchors, that's allowed to match;

```
234.41.123.0
```

You may want to include either `^` and `$` in your regex (start/end of line anchors) or word boundary anchors (`\b`).